# Change default EAP type in hostapd

Tags: network, configuration, peap, 802.1x, wpa2-eap

I'm trying to change the default EAP type in hostapd but I am not able to understand how to do that.

Here's what I've found reading the `hostapd.conf` file:

```
> # NAI Realm information
> # One or more realm can be advertised. Each nai_realm line adds a new realm to
> # the set. These parameters provide information for stations using Interworking
> # network selection to allow automatic connection to a network based on
> # credentials.
> # format: <encoding>,<NAI Realm(s)>[,<EAP Method 1>][,<EAP Method 2>][,...]
> # encoding:
> # 0 = Realm formatted in accordance with IETF RFC 4282
> # 1 = UTF-8 formatted character string that is not formatted in
> #     accordance with IETF RFC 4282
> # NAI Realm(s): Semi-colon delimited NAI Realm(s)
> # EAP Method: <EAP Method>[:<[AuthParam1:Val1]>][<[AuthParam2:Val2]>][...]
> # EAP Method types, see:
> # http://www.iana.org/assignments/eap-numbers/eap-numbers.xhtml#eap-numbers-4
> # AuthParam (Table 8-188 in IEEE Std 802.11-2012):
> # ID 2 = Non-EAP Inner Authentication Type
> # 1 = PAP, 2 = CHAP, 3 = MSCHAP, 4 = MSCHAPV2
> # ID 3 = Inner authentication EAP Method Type
> # ID 5 = Credential Type
> # 1 = SIM, 2 = USIM, 3 = NFC Secure Element, 4 = Hardware Token,
> # 5 = Softoken, 6 = Certificate, 7 = username/password, 9 = Anonymous,
> # 10 = Vendor Specific
> #nai_realm=0,example.com;example.net
> # EAP methods EAP-TLS with certificate and EAP-TTLS/MSCHAPv2 with
> # username/password
> #nai_realm=0,example.org,13[5:6],21[2:4][5:7]
```